# Why does St. Jerome translate αληθείας as caritatis in 1 Pet. 1:22?

Tags: greek, 1-peter, latin-vulgate, latin

Why does St. Jerome translate αληθείας as *caritatis* in [1 Pet. 1:22](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=67&ch=1&l=22-#x)?

> *obedientia* [υπακοή] *caritatis* [αληθείας = "of the truth"]

He uses "*non obedire veritati*" for "αληθεία μη πείθεσθαι" in [Gal. 3:1](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=55&ch=3&l=1-#x).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is considered a textual variation.  We have no explanation as to why.  It appears that his Greek text had τῆς ἀγάπης instead of τῆς ἀληθείας.

> ```
>  1:22      ἀληθείας {A}
> ```
>
> After ἀληθείας the Textus Receptus, following the later uncials (K P 049 056 0142) and most minuscules, adds the phrase διὰ πνεύματος. These words, whose absence from such early and good witnesses as 72 א A B C Ψ 33 1739 al cannot easily be explained if they were present originally, appear to be a theological expansion introduced by a copyist. In the West several Old Latin manuscripts and the Vulgate replaced ἀληθείας with caritatis (“charity”), and one witness (Speculum) expanded with fidei per spiritum (“faith through the Spirit”).

Metzger, B. M., United Bible Societies. (1994). A textual commentary on the Greek New Testament, second edition a companion volume to the United Bible Societies’ Greek New Testament (4th rev. ed.) (pp. 617–618). London; New York: United Bible Societies.

Comment: Excellent answer! +1